# Finding an expression for the CDF of sum of two random variables $X, Y$ conditioned on the value of one variable $Y$: find $P(X + Y < c | Y = b)$

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

This is related to my other question on renewal processes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947852/renewal-theory-probability-of-residual-lifetime-gamma-t-x-conditioned-on-c

$X, Y$ are continuous random variables, possibly not independent, and we know the $CDF$ of $X + Y$ which is given by $F(c)$. What is $P(X + Y < c | Y = b)$ in terms of $F(c)$?

Attempt:

$P(X + Y < c | Y = b) = \frac{P(X + Y < c)}{P(Y = b)}$. The numerator is just $F(c)$, but how do I find the denominator in terms of the given $CDF$? Another confusion I have is why is the denominator not just $0$ since $Y$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: Note that $$P(X+Y<c|Y=b)=\frac{P(X+Y<c\cap Y=b)}{P(Y=b)}$$

Comment: Isn't that just the definition of conditional probability? How do I proceed?

Comment: Ah, you mean the numerator isn't just $F(c)$.. how do i write it then as a function of the cdf?

Comment: @gunes Also, aren't we conditioning on an event with $0$ probability in this case? Is that allowed? $Y$ is a continuous random variable, so $P(Y = b) = 0$.

Comment: Writing $Z=X+Y$ and noting you make no assumptions whatsoever about $(X,Y)$ apart from having continuous marginals, you are asking how to compute conditional probabilities for *any* pair of continuous random variables $(Y,Z).$ In particular, conditional probabilities do not depend solely on the marginal distribution of $Z$ (if they did, all continuous variables would automatically be independent), which makes your question unanswerable.

Comment: @whuber I understand. This is the link to the original question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947852/renewal-theory-probability-of-residual-lifetime-gamma-t-x-conditioned-on-c), so there are more assumptions on $(X, Y)$ but I thought it could be done in general too, not just for my specific $X, Y$.